# Mathematica crashes after symbolic integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a very serious problem. I want to integrate the function func symbolically. I've checked the result numerical which agrees with literature but I need the analytical expression of the computed integral. However, mathematica crashes after some time. Can somebody take a look at this and help me out

```
func = (1/(15 \[Pi]))2 (x (-2 + x + z) (15 x^3 + x^2 (-30 + 32 z) + 
      x (90 + 46 z + 7 z^2) + 2 (-75 + 32 z - 7 z^2 + z^3)) + 
   2 (-2 + x + z)^3 (-1 + x^2 + 2 x (-2 + z) - 4 z + z^2) Log[
     1 - x] - 
   2 (71 - 115 x + 40 x^2 + 5 (-23 + 4 x) z + 
      5 (14 - 9 x + 15 x^2) z^2 - 5 (7 - 8 x + 2 x^2) z^3 - 
      5 (-2 + x) z^4 - z^5) Log[-((-1 + z)/(-1 + x))] - 
   2 (-1 + x + z) (71 + x^4 - 44 z + 26 z^2 - 9 z^3 + z^4 + 
      x^3 (-9 + 4 z) + x^2 (26 - 27 z + 6 z^2) + 
      x (-44 + 52 z - 27 z^2 + 4 z^3)) Log[-1 + x + z] - 
   60 (-2 + x + z) (-1 + x + z) (Log[-1 + z]^2 - 
      Log[-((-1 + x + z)/(-1 + x))]^2)) Subscript[\[Alpha], S]
```

The integration is given as

```
Integrate[func, {z, 1, 2}, {x, s, (2 - z)}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < s <= 0.9, 0 < Subscript[\[Alpha], S] < 1}]
```

Edit: I changed the integration because of some typos.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title—one that relates to the specific content of your question, not one that could apply to millions of unrelated questions.

Comment: `Heaviside` is not a built-in function. Have you defined it? Or did you mean [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html)?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Of course I meant HeavisideTheta

Comment: If `0 < s <= 9/10` then integral is **Zero**.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk for Alpha_s =.5 it is between 0.105  and -0.14 which you can verify by just plotting and using NIntegrate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash with 12.1.0 on macOS. After several minutes of running, it returned a result. With crash issues, always post complete version and OS information, and include precise (reproducible) instructions on how to trigger the crash.

Answer (score 3):

You have to help Mathematica (12.1 on Windows 10) a little bit, but then you can get an answer in a few minutes:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 int1 = Integrate[func, x];
 int2 = Collect[Expand[ (int1 /. x -> (2 - z)) - ( int1 /. x -> s)], 
   s];
 int3 = Together@
   ParallelSum[PrintTemporary[j]; 
    Integrate[int2[[j]], {z, 1, 2}, 
     Assumptions -> {0 < s <= 0.9}], {j, Length@int2}];
 ]
```

The result is a bit messy and you may want to simplify the `Log` and `PolyLog` functions.
Plotting can be done by:

```
p[s_] = int3 /. Subscript[\[Alpha], S] :> .5;
Plot[Chop[p[s]], {s, 0, .9}]
```

Which can be verified by comparing to

```
Plot[NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[func /. Subscript[\[Alpha], S] :> .5], {z, 1, 2}, {x, 
   s, (2 - z)}], {s, 0, .9}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "func"}]
```